# Build $n $ like a sum of $1 $ an $2$, no double $1$.

Tags: combinatorics

This exercise is inspired by reality, and this is why I note it here.

Some inventory workers scan items on shelves using a hand scanner. A very fast method is to count items in a group using just the $1$ and $2$ buttons on the hand scanner. Keeping the eyes locked on the marchandise and using blind the digits keypad is a very fast method of counting, incredibly fast.

For exemple, $4 = 1 + 2 + 1$. Given the restriction that no consecutive $1$'s should be introduced on keypad, in how many ways a number $n$ may be composed ?
Eg:

$ 5 = 1+2+2 = 2+1+2 = 2+2+1$ - there are three ways to get the sum $5$.

(Also, one can try this solve not using immediately the OEIS)

thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried?  I would think the first few values would reveal the general answer...

Comment: Hello lulu : me ? me I jumped immediatelly on OEIS and I lost the juice !

Comment: Again, just write out the first few values.  The sequence is clearly recursive in nature...  If you need a Hint:  separately keep track of the number of ways to do it starting with $1$ and the number of ways to do it starting with $2$.

Comment: Again, once you see the answer in OEIS, there is no more fun :) c'mon Lulu ! :)

Comment: Stars and bars.

Comment: Don't know what you want here...you already have the answer, right?   OEIS should certainly get the job done.  For the recursion: If a good sum for $n$ starts with $2$, the rest is a good sum for $n-2$.  If it starts with $1$, the next term must be $2$ and the rest is a good sum for $n-3$.  The desired recursion follows at once.

Comment: As you already know the answer, you seem to be offering this as challenge or puzzle for others. That is not really the purpose for this forum, which is to help people solve math problems they have. There is a Puzzle forum in Stack Exchange where such threads are more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued working so here is how I obtained a puristic GF solution.

We have here a binary string with restrictions. Using PIE, the generating function turns to be:

$$ 1 + y \over1  - x  - xy$$

which is strongly related to Fibonacci numbers. By adding weights of 1 an 2 associated with the two symbols used in the binary string,

$$ 1 + ty \over1  - t^2x  - t^2x.ty$$

We are now interested in the coefficients of $t^k$. We can equate $x=y=1$ and obtain

$$ 1 + t \over 1  - t^2  - t^3$$

that will generate the Padovan sequence.